# MATLAB - Statistical matrices comparison to find relations

Tags: matlab, statistical-test

I am puzzled by a problem in MATLAB. I wish to do a comparison between two equally sized matrices (100x100) with different values inside. I want to find similiarities or relations between the matrices content. Since both matrices came from different projects an normalization was needed to make them compareable.
Now I am struggeling with the comparison.

A value by value correlationcoefficient would be sufficient I guess.

Any suggestions or even code examples ?

All the best
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Thanks for an thought that was Wasser for this post.